# RSYNC doesn't overwriting root files

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` like this:

```
rsync . -vzp --rsync-path "sudo rsync" --chown=user:user  --exclude .git --progress -e "ssh -p <PORT>" user@<PUBLIC_IP>:/home/user/rsync/
```

The on the destination server there are commands like `chown root:root`. And after that another `rsync` command. But `rsync` doesn't overwrite files that have root ownership. Is there any flag in `rsync` that allow me to overwrite root files?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried using `--rsync-path "sudo rsync"` but I wouldn't expect your way to work, usually by specifying a path a program would use the path first to establish that the file exists and is executable, "sudo rsync" isn't a valid path !

Perhaps you could specify a shell script (that you'll need to write) that does what you want and relays the arguments, but your sudo would have no way to get your password !

Secondly if you specify names when changing ownership, those names need to exist on the remote system, using numeric Id's would be better.

If you are transferring files that are owned by both root and a user, I would recommend to login on as root at the server and use `--numeric-ids`

Probably best to rethink your strategy.

Two rsync runs one for user the second for root files, so that you can control the mapping correctly on the restore. This would work if you don't have root access on the server. BUT it would introduce a security risk. root files store on the server would be readable by the admin on that server!

It wouldn't matter as far as rsync is concerned that they are stored owned by user, as long as you have root access locally so that you can map them back on the restore. Apart from the security risk.

The root owned files are like that for a reason, they might contain sensitive information (keys, passwords, etc) that shouldn't be exposed on the server, think encryption !

You need to provide more information about your aim (which includes restoration) and what type of access you have on your local and remote systems.

[Edit]

Here's a good answer on Server fault, I had forgotten about the fake root option, https://serverfault.com/a/755824

Comment: `--rsync-path "sudo rsync"` does work

Answer (score 0):

The command settings you have used will not descend into subdirectories, so it's not a case of refusing to overwrite root-owned files but simply that they are not even being considered. You should also include the `--times` (`-t`) flag so that `rsync` can skip files it's already copied.

Try this instead:

```
rsync -vzrtp --rsync-path 'sudo rsync' --chown=user:user  --exclude .git --progress -e 'ssh -p {PORT}' ./ user@{PUBLIC_IP}:/home/user/rsync/
```

Bear in mind, though, that you'll be writing files owned by root into a directory that appears to be owned by "user". This isn't generally good practice but it will work.

If this is for backup purposes you may prefer to use the `--fake-super` option on the remote side (`-M` applies the option only to the far end), which will remove the need to run the remote service as root. It requires a remote filesystem that can handle extended attributes (`ext4` and other native Linux filesystems can do this). In this case the command can be modified slightly to capture all the metadata rather than just permissions and times:

```
rsync -avzP -M--fake-super --exclude .git -e "ssh -p {PORT}" ./ user@{PUBLIC_IP}:/home/user/rsync/
```

When you come to restore files from such a backup, you must use `-M-fake-super` for it, too, so that the remote `rsync` server uses the data it's saved in the extended attributes. Be aware also, that if you do transition to this variant, none of the root-owned files and directories you've previously copied will be overwritable, so you'll need to move them out of the way first (or revert the ownership).

Finally, remember that while you're testing you can include the `--dry-run` (`-n`) option to show you what would happen but without actually changing anything.